# Deleting AWS CloudFormation Stack does not release Elastic IP allocated to Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation Stack that creates a Network Load Balancer and assigns a newly allocated Elastic IP to it as follows

```
"MyLoadBalancer":{
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
    "Properties" : {

      "Scheme": "internet-facing",
      "Type": "network",
      "SubnetMappings": [
        {
          "AllocationId": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "MyElasticIP",
              "AllocationId"
            ]
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "LoadBalancerSubnetRef"
        }
      } ]
    }
  },
  "MyElasticIP": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",

    "Properties": {
      "Domain": "vpc"
    }
  }
```

This creates as expected, but when it comes to delete, the Load Balancer is correctly dissasociated from the Elastic IP and removed, but the IP itself is not released. I can manually 'Disassociate Address' using the console, so not sure why this hangs on?

Comment: Some of the resources of AWS needs to be deleted/released manually. This can be called as a feature or the disadvantage of AWS. But you have to release the Elastic IP manually.